# Groovy overriding method fails when method comes from interface

Tags: java, groovy

Adding or overriding any method in groovy with the help of ExpandoMetaClass works perfectly, until the method I am trying to override is not overriding interface method. The following code's output is `mew, I am hungry`, but I expect it to be `mew-mew`. What am I doing wrong?

```
interface Cat {
   String mew()
}
class Barsik implements Cat {
   String mew(){ "mew, I am hungry" }
}

Barsik.metaClass.mew = {->
   "mew-mew"
}

Cat barsik = new Barsik()
println(barsik.mew())
```

Comment: Think that's https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3493.  As a workaround, you can override the instance meta method, or the interface one

Comment: @tim_yates: According to the comment of 30/Jun/15 in that issue, you have to override the instance *and* the interface meta methods.